# What is the difference between statsd client and the statsd daemon?

Tags: monitoring, graphite, statsd, graphite-carbon, whisper

I have an application that I wish to monitor graphically.

I am using [this](https://github.com/alexcesaro/statsd) StatsD client.  I am using [Graphite](https://hub.docker.com/r/graphiteapp/graphite-statsd/) as the backend.  I have a question about the basic workflow:

We use the StatsD client in order to include metrics within our application.  These metrics are then sent in the form of UDP packets (usually).  Graphite (specifically [Carbon](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/carbon-daemons.html) within Graphite) captures these packets and stores them in the [Whisper](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whisper.html) database as time-series data.

What exactly then, is the role of the [StatsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) daemon?  I have written a working application using only the StatsD client and Graphite.  Where am I missing the usage of StatsD daemon?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same question, so I'm going to answer it here even thogh the post is 7 months old.

From what I could gather (as [explained here](https://thenewstack.io/collecting-metrics-using-statsd-a-standard-for-real-time-monitoring/)), a StatsD Deamon is synonymous to a StatsD Server. In your case, it's Carbon/Graphite or maybe a StatsD specific component within your Graphite Stack.

In my company, for instance, we use the StatsD Beats Daemon within the ELK-Stack.